# Flyway connecting to a Database Cluster on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, flyway

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Cluster using Flyway-Commandline. It works fine from DOS using:

```
# Ommitting the other params for brevity: jarDir, locations, user, password, driver etc
flyway clean -url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = my_host_1)(PORT=8020))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = my_host_2)(PORT=8020))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SERVICE_NAME)))"
```

But when I do the same on linux I get an error:

```
ERROR: FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
ERROR: Occured in com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection() at line 56
ERROR: Caused by oracle.net.ns.NetException: NL Exception was generated
ERROR: Occured in oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAddrTree() at line 626
```

It works fine on both platforms if I connect directly to one of the hosts directly using:

```
flyway clean -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@my_host_1:8020/MY_SERVICE_NAME
```

The problem is that when one host in the cluster goes down, which happens regularly, this stops working.

Comment: try asking this on [server fault](http://serverfault.com/), you might get more of a response there

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with your Linux environment and not with Flyway itself.